# Animated placemark and MarkerClusterPlus

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I was using MarkerClusterPlus, v.2.0.9 and just by chance noticed that if clusterer hide animated placemark (you zoomed out) and after that you show placemark (you zoomed in), than placemark stopped to be animated.
For example, if you have bounced placemark, after hide/show you'll see simple placemark.

After that I found, that there is 2.0.14 version exists, but this effect is still exists.

Thanks,
Dmitry

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 2.0.14 is the latest version. It will help if you include a small section of code with your question that shows your exact problem.

Also, there is a [Utility Library v3 Issue List](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/issues/list); have a look around on there. I have seen issues on that list that sound similar to yours. You may be able to find a similar or related issue and up-vote the issue to raise the priority of your problem. Or if your issue is different, you can double-check everything and if it's pretty clear you have a true issue, you can submit an issue report there.

Comment: I've create test map.
This is a link
http://www.dodge-caliber.ru/index.php/howtofind2

The left placemark is bounce.
After zoom out - create cluster - zoom in - you'll see it stop bounce